# GLFW and C crashed

Tags: c, glfw

I'm having problems splitting glfw window creation in two functions (CreateWindow, CreateGameLoop). I've tried two ways of doing it but one of them causes the window to crash.
The first example has the CreateGameLoop void in main.
The second example has the CreateGameLoop void in CreateWindow.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>

void CreateGameLoop(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();    
    }
    
    glfwTerminate();
}

void CreateWindow(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Game Window", 0, 0);
    if (!window)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    CreateWindow(window);
    CreateGameLoop(window);
    return 0;
}
```

working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>

void CreateGameLoop(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();    
    }
    
    glfwTerminate();
}

void CreateWindow(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Game Window", 0, 0);
    if (!window)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD\n");
    }
    
    CreateGameLoop(window);
}

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    CreateWindow(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should pass `GLFWwindow**` to aux methods, otherwise the pointer is not carried outside.